# Filling grouped object background with color in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, shapes, background

Is there any way to fill grouped objects background in Illustrator?

Below is example how i want it, right now i simply just put white square behind them.

[image: Here is example how i want it to look]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *really* don't want to create a second object for the background, you can use some **Appearance Panel** trickery to add one....

- **Group** the lines
- Add a new fill in the **Appearance Panel**
- Move the fill **below** the `Contents` in the panel
- With the Fill highlighted choose `Effect > Convert to Shape > Rectangle`
- Set the Options for `Extra Width` and `Extra Height` to zero.

[image]

However, there's really little reason to *not* merely draw a box behind the lines to create a fill. Then merely group the lines and the box.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it right.

For a background to exist there, you need a separate white object in the exact same shape and size as your group.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have done it with a rectangle behind the group *is* the way to "fill" behind a "group"- this is done often- you could also group the rectangle with the lines so they could easily be moved around together.

Alternately, you could combine the rectangle and the group of lines into a compound path (Object>compound path>make) so it is all one "object"- the disadvantage to this is that you would have a border around the entire shape which would be whatever your stroke color is- your example did not have this

[image]